# Rings with given additive or multiplicative groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

1. Does there exist a ring $(A, \oplus_A, \odot_A)$ whose additive group is $\mathbb{Q}^*$, meaning $(A, \oplus_A) \cong (\mathbb{Q}^*, \cdot)$?
2. Does there exist a ring $(B, \oplus_B, \odot_B)$ whose additive group is $\mathbb{Q}_{> 0}$, meaning $(B, \oplus_B) \cong (\mathbb{Q}_{> 0}, \cdot)$?
3. Does there exist a ring $(C, \oplus_C, \odot_C)$ whose multiplicative group is $\mathbb{Q}$, meaning $(C^*, \odot_C) \cong (\mathbb{Q}, +)$?

About question (1.): If there is such a ring $A$ with a ring isomorphism $\varphi: \mathbb{Q}^* \to A$, then we have $\varphi(-1) \oplus_A \varphi(-1) = \varphi((-1) \cdot (-1)) = \varphi(1) = 0_A$. This means that $(A, \oplus_A)$ has torsion elements. However, I don't know if this information is helpful.

About question (3.): If there is such a ring $C$ with a group isomorphism $\psi: \mathbb{Q} \to C^*$, then we have $\psi^{-1}(-1_C) + \psi^{-1}(-1_C) = \psi^{-1}((-1_C)^2) = \psi^{-1}(1_C) = 0$, which implies $\psi^{-1}(-1_C) = 0$, so $-1_C = 1_C$ and $1_C \oplus_C 1_C = 0_C$. This implies $x \oplus_C x = x \odot_C (1_C \oplus_C 1_C) = x \odot_C 0_C = 0_C$ for any $x \in C$. So we get a ring homomorphism $\mathbb{F}_2 \to C$, turning $C$ into an $\mathbb{F}_2$-algebra and in particular an $\mathbb{F}_2$-vector space. I believe that this should lead to a contradiction, but I don't know how to continue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\DeclareMathOperator{\bbZ}{\mathbb{Z}}$
$\DeclareMathOperator{\bbQ}{\mathbb{Q}}$
$\DeclareMathOperator{\bbF}{\mathbb{F}}$

All these questions have a positive answer.

The ring $\bbZ[x]$ has additive group $\oplus_{n=0}^\infty \bbZ$, which is isomorphic to the multiplicative group $\bbQ_{>0}$ (the latter is free on the primes). The ring $\bbZ[x]\times \bbZ_2$ has additive group isomorphic to the multiplicative group $\bbQ^*$.

If $R$ is any integral domain and $G$ is any orderable group, then the only units in the group ring $R[G]$ are the trivial ones (of the form $ug$ where $u$ is a unit of $R$ and $g\in G$).  This means the unit group of $R[G]$ is isomorphic to $R^\times\times G$.  Since the additive group $\bbQ$ is orderable, the group of units of $\bbF_2[\bbQ]$ is isomorphic to $\bbQ$.